# How to configure sass-loader to produce only CSS from SCSS

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to use 2 modules in webpack.config
Along with building js bundle I'd like to build CSS for web page, but always got error

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/company-style.scss 1:3
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    > h1 {
    |   color: #c43f4c; }
```

company-style.scss

```
$myred: #c43f4c;
h1 {
  color: $myred;
}
```

Could you please look at cssConfig in following listing. I can't understand how to properly config loader

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
var config = {
    // common Configuration
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            }
            ,{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }]
            }

            ,{
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

};

var bundleConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
    name: "js-bundle",
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
});
var cssConfig = Object.assign({}, config,{
    name: "css-bundle",
    entry: "./src/sass/company-style.scss",
    output: {
        filename: "company-style.css",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                /*use: [{
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }]*/
                use: ['sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
});
module.exports = [
    bundleConfig, cssConfig
];
```

There no problem with **bundleConfig** module. bundle.js built and working

Comment: Just to understand, do you really want to make a separate CSS file or do you simply want your app to include the SCSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to produce a standalone CSS file from the SCSS file.

Take a look at [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
      chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That's real problem wit javascript community: - instead answering simple question and fix the problem - suggest patch and than another patch, and another... And as result "node-modules" dependencies grows exponentially. ufff...

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it is only solution. Thank you again.

Comment: @AlexeiP yeah I remember this was a confusing thing to figure out initially. It helps to understand that the purpose of Webpack is to product **one** Javascript bundle. So if you use `style-loader`, then the CSS actually gets bundled up into JS. The styles are then applied when the JS is parsed by the browser. You can see this behavior if you make a dummy project that imports a CSS file and then read the `bundle.js` that Webpack produces. To get any other behavior (like moving/emitting standalone CSS files), we use Webpack plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen combined loaders listed like that, have you tried something like this?

```
use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
```

Comment: that is the same as this one.

Comment: @EMC The point was to produce CSS file. As I understand **'css-loader'** takes css output from **sass-loader** to produce javascript.